# How to stop a temporary cursor from showing up when touching QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, touchscreen

On a touch screen application, there are various Textboxes (QLineEdits). The mouse/cursor is hidden, however the problem is that touching with a finger to focus on the texbox will show a temporary cursor. Note this is NOT the blinking cursor that sits in the textbox. It seems to be the actual mouse cursor that temporarily appears but then disappears after a few seconds. Is there a way to prevent that temporary cursor from appearing?

Comment: As a wild guess, QGUIApplication::setOverrideCursor(BlankCursor) might do the trick.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks, ill give that a go

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Just want to note that Jeremy's above answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeremy's answer worked for me.

```
QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::BlankCursor);
```